# PHP array pass value by reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have a very little piece of code for testing an array_walk test.

I thought that I could do the same with foreach but then when I pass the value it doesn't get modified:

```
<?php
$frutas = [ "d" => "limón", "a" => "naranja", "b" => "banana", "c" => "manzana" ];

function test_alter(&$elemento)
{
  $elemento = "prefijo: $elemento";
  echo "$elemento <br>";
}

foreach($frutas as $clave => $valor) {
  test_alter($valor, $clave);
}
print_r( $frutas ); 
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
prefijo: limón
prefijo: naranja
prefijo: banana
prefijo: manzana
Array ( [d] => limón [a] => naranja [b] => banana [c] => manzana )
```

Obviously not modifying array value although its passed by reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing `$valor` to the function ... `foreach` values are not 'referenced' values, so you are altering a temporary value, not the actual array value  ...

try this in your foreach loop:

```
test_alter($frutas[$clave]);
```

or, you could:

```
foreach($frutas as $clave => &$valor){
    test_alter($valor, $clave);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, both worked but I noticed in the second example that its not necessary to pass $clave to test_alter isnt it? (I deleted it and got the same result).

Comment: I was just using the code you had ... you are passing `$clave` in your original example ... I agree that it is not necessary, as your `test_alter` function does not accept a second parameter

Comment: Oh, was my mistake (I was editing it and trying different things). Thanks a lot for your time.